# How to input year and month?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to input date strings comprising a month and year, e.g. January 2000.

According to the [man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm), %B (and %b) "On input, matches the name of the month in the given locale (in either abbreviated or full form, or any unique prefix of either form)", but I can't make this work:

```
% clock scan "January 2000" -format "%B %Y"
1475881200
% clock format 1475881200 -format "%B %Y"
October 2016
```

It looks to me as though Tcl doesn't understand something and is defaulting to today's date.

I'd like my command to return `946684800`, the result of `[clock scan 2000-01-01 -format %Y-%M-%D]`

Is there a problem with `[clock scan]`, the documentation or my reading of the documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the same problem, but only if I don't specify the day of the month. If I do, things work:

```
% clock scan "1 January 2000" -format "%d %B %Y"
946684800
% clock format 946684800
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2000
```

While yes, I suppose this is a bug (and you probably ought to report it on the core.tcl-lang.org issue tracker), adding in a (fake?) day of the month seems like an easy enough workaround. After all, without it should the parser default to the current day-of-month or the first or some other day? What's the representative day? Specify it and the problem goes away.

Comment: "Add a dummy day". Thank you. I must be losing my touch :-(. I couldn't find an issue tracker at core.tcl-lang.org Agreed, in view of the questions you raise that it's probably best to leave things as they are, so would (ave been) happy to see such an issue closed fairly promptly.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. It appears you need to also specify a day

```
$ echo 'puts [clock format [clock scan "January 2000" -format "%B %Y"]]' | tclsh8.6
Sat Oct 08 00:00:00 EDT 2016

$ echo 'puts [clock format [clock scan "1 January 2000" -format "%d %B %Y"]]' | tclsh8.6
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2000
```

I see in the documentation (http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm) a section starting with

> The date is determined according to the fields that are present in the preprocessed format string. In order of preference:

ending with

> 7. If none of the above rules results in a usable date, the date of the base time in the given time zone is used.

It's probably in #3 where you're expecting to match but aren't.